# natbib does not properly show author-year

Tags: citing, natbib

I imported natbib properly:

```
\usepackage{natbib}
```

Now, when citing in the parenthetical style:

```
\citep[p. 12]{MyKey}
```

, where I am sure that my key exists and the author and year are set, in the pdf output it still shows

```
(1, p.12)
```

However, I would like to see

```
(Author Year, p.12)
```

Did I miss something?

Also, doing

```
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
```

doesn't help.

Comment: This behaviour depends on the bibliography style in use: which are you using?

Comment: you were faster, damn :)

Answer (score 10):

Sorry, but I already solved it.
The solution is to use the right bibliographystyle, namely:

```
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
```

Now it works.

Comment: Does natbib support any other bibliography styles or only this one?

Comment: Natbib (latest version: 8.31b, 2010/09/13) comes with the following three bib style (.bst) files: `plainnat`, `unsrtnat`, and `abbrevnat`. However, it is so flexible that it supports most all bst files out there, even the ones that come with (original) BibTeX  (i.e., `plain.bst`, `abbrev.bst`, and `abbrev.bst`). It supports both *numeric* and *author-year* citation systems. If you can't find a bibliography style file that meets your specific needs, the tex file `makebst.tex` (written by the author of natbib) lets you create a new one from scratch.